# Proving a given assignation over a sigma algebra is a measure.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X$ be a no countable set and $M=\lbrace A \subset X |\mbox{A is countable or} A^{c} \: \mbox{is countable}  \rbrace$. If I define the assignation

$$\mu(A)=\begin{cases}
       0 & \: if A \: \mbox{is countable} \\
       1       & if A^{C} \: \mbox{is countable}
    \end{cases}$$

I claim this is not a measure since it seems to happen the additivity doesnt work here. For example:

Let $A_{1},A_{2}\in X$ and both subsets are countable, so $A_{1} \cup A_{2}$ is countable. Then by one side we have that $\mu(A_{1} \cup A_{2})=1$, and by other side we have that $\mu(A_{1})+ \mu(A_{2})=1+1=2$ so

$$\mu(A_{1} \cup A_{2}) \neq \mu(A_{1})+ \mu(A_{2}).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the your set function is a measure in that sigma algebra.

Indeed let $\{A_n:n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ disjoint.

If all are countable then their countable union is countable so $$\mu(\bigcup_n A_n)=0=\sum_n\mu(A_n)$$

If some $A_m$ is uncountable then $A_n \subseteq A_m^c, \forall n \neq m$
and by definition of the sigma algebra $A_m^c$ is countable.

So $\mu(A_n)=0 ,\forall n\neq m$ and $\mu(A_m)=1$

Since $(\bigcup_nA_n)^c \subseteq A_m^c$ we have that $\mu(\bigcup_nA_n)=1=\sum_n\mu(A_n)$

If $\{A_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is any countable collection of pairwise disjoint sets in  the sigma algebra, then it can contain at most one uncountable set because if $A_n,A_m$ are two disjoint uncountable sets, then $A^c_n,A^c_m$ are countable, so $A^c_n\cup A^c_m$ is countable, and thus $A_n \cap A_m=(A^c_n \cup A^c_m)^c$ is uncountable  thus non-empty, which is a contradiction,since the sets are assumed disjoint.

Comment: Why $A_{n} \subseteq A_{m}^{c}$ for $n \neq m$ follows from $A_{m}$ uncoutable?

Comment: No..It follows from the disjointness of the sets

Comment: Still dont see that detail. I mean if i take $x \in A_{n}$ then $x \notin A_{r}$ for every $r \in \mathbb{N}$ such $r \neq n$ including $r=m$  so $x \in A_{r}^{c}$ for every $r \in \mathbb{N}$ such $r \neq n$in particular $x \in A_{m}^{c}$

Comment: Since all the sets are disjoint,take $n \neq m$ and  then you will have that $A_n \cap A_m=\emptyset$ so $A_n \subseteq A_m^c$.

Comment: Thanks! My justification above is right?

Comment: Yes it is fine, since $x$ belongs to the intersection of all the sets $A_r^c$ including $A_m^c$ and this intersection is a subset of $A_m^c$

Comment: Thanks Mario! You were really helpful. Aprecciate it!

Comment: You are welcome....Glad i could help.

Comment: Another doubt ; why $(U A_{n})^{c} /subset A_{m}^{c}$ ?  Also we need to prove there is no more than one uncountable set in the original union right? I think an argument by contradiction works here @MariosGretsas

Comment: $(\cup A_n)^c=\cap_nA_n^c \subseteq A_m^c$ Note that $A_m$ is also in the intercestions and union.

Comment: @Cos i edited my answer..